# Which part of model should handle database inserts?

Tags: c#, single-responsibility-principle

Title probably doesn't describe my problem too well, I'll be glad if somebody could edit it to something more appropriate. Anyways:

I got a component that is supposed to return product price given its `id`. It implements an interface like this one:

```
interface IProductPriceFetcher
{
    double GetPrice(int id);
}
```

Now, the price can be fetched from **3 different** sources:

- web service
- directly from website source code (scrapping)
- as a final fallback (both webservice and website are inaccessible), most recent price from local database is returned

To play around this 3-different-sources issue I've implemented class like this:

```
class MainFetcher : IProductPriceFetcher
{
    public double GetPrice(int id)
    {
        var priceFetcher = this.factory.GetWebServiceFetcher()
                        ?? this.factory.GetWebsiteFetcher()
                        ?? this.factory.GetLocalDatabaseFetcher();
        return priceFetcher.GetPrice(id);
    }
}
```

Each method from factory returns `IProductPriceFetcher` of course, with side note that first two can fail and return `null`; I assumed `GetLocalDatabaseFetcher` will always return meaningful object tho.

#### My "general wondering... ment"

Upon successful webservice/website call, I want fetched price to be inserted into local datbase, as a future fallback case. Now my question is: which part of code above should be responsible for that? Should it be one of the concrete web fetchers that returns price? Or "aggregator" fetcher (`MainFetcher`), as it also has knowledge over what's the source of price? Should I raise some event? Inject yet another interface with DB calls? Change design to better?

Why did it even occur as an issue to me? Well, I tried to keep the code clean (worry not, it's only pet project for my spare time - exactly for solving problems like this) possibly with SRP/SoC in mind. Now I seem to have problems switching from this mindset - I mean, how could possibly something that fetches webpages also be doing database inserts? Oh, come on! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a super-decoupled design, I would implement a [Decorator](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx) class like the following and use it to wrap both the WebServiceFetcher and the WebsiteFetcher:

```
class DatabaseCachingFetcherDecorator : IProductPriceFetcher
{
    private readonly IProductPriceFetcher innerFetcher;

    public DatabaseCachingFetcherDecorator(IProductPriceFetcher fetcher)
    {
        this.innerFetcher = fetcher;
    }

    public double GetPrice(int id)
    {
        double price = this.innerFetcher.GetPrice(id);

        if (price != 0) // or some other value representing "price not found"
        {
            SavePriceToDatabase(id, price);
        }

        return price;
    }

    private SavePriceToDatabase(int id, double price)
    {
        // TODO: Implement...
    }
}
```

Then your factory would implement the following methods:

```
public IProductPriceFetcher GetWebServiceFetcher()
{
    return new DatabaseCachingFetcherDecorator(new WebServiceFetcher());
}

public IProductPriceFetcher GetWebsiteFetcher()
{
    return new DatabaseCachingFetcherDecorator(new WebsiteFetcher());
}
```

This design decouples your actual fetchers from your caching mechanism.

**EDIT:** I misread your design slightly with this answer, as I assumed that the GetPrice method would return some sort of NULL value if the price couldn't be fetched, rather than the factory returning a NULL value. I think the factory returning NULL smells a bit, since a factory's responsibility is to reliably return objects. I would consider changing your `GetPrice` method interface to return a `double?` perhaps, to allow for "price not found".

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like if you needed a "Cache". Caching is typically implemented either as a kind of aspect or dependency which you inject into your `Fetcher` implementation. Below I assume `IPriceCache` with sort of `IDictionary` interface, but you could of course insert whatever abstraction you require. I also suggest to abstract away the data sources for price fetchers...:

```
class MainFetcher : IPriceFetcher {

 IEnumerable< IPriceSource > mSource;
 IPriceCache mCache;

 public MainFetcher( IEnumerable< IPriceSource > pSource, IPriceCache pCache )
 {
     mSource = pSource;
     mCache = pCache; 
 }

 public double GetPrice(int pID)
 {
     double tPrice;
     // get from cache
     if (mCache.TryGet(pID, out tPrice) {
         return tPrice;
     } else {
         // throws if no source found
         tPrice = mSource
             .First(tArg => tArg != null)
             .GetPrice(pID);
         // add to cache
         mCache.Add(pID, tPrice);
     }
 }
}
```